# Responsive grid using CSS display:flex

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to display my flexbox from 5 columns (A,B,C,D,E) to 2 columns once the screen gets to 900px and smaller.

My html:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
</div>
```

My CSS set up:

```
.container{
  background:#231F20;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}

.box{
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  border:5px solid #ADA8AA;
  color:white;
  padding:2rem;
  font-size:2rem;
  background:#423e3f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

I managed to get from 5 columns to 2 columns once it gets smaller using

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .box{
         flex: auto;
         width: 50%;
    }
}
```

My problem is the last box (E) is fully stretch, I would like to display only at 50% wide, how could I do that?

Working example [here](https://codepen.io/vincentccw/pen/XeWPrX).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your css to

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
    .box {
      width: 50%;
      flex: auto;
    }
    .box:last-child {
       max-width: 50%;
    }
}
```

You will get this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/mBdGNg (it's a fork of your sample)

Comment: Thanks, why I didn't think about it in the first place

Answer (score 1):

You could apply a `max-width` to the last .box element as follows:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
  .box{
   width: 50%;
   flex: auto;
  }
  .box:last-child {
    max-width:50%;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML code**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">A</div>
  <div class="box">B</div>
  <div class="box">C</div>
  <div class="box">D</div>
  <div class="box">E</div>
</div>
```

**CSS code**

```
.container{
  background:#231F20;
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.box{
  flex:1;
  text-align:center;
  border:5px solid #ADA8AA;
  color:white;
  padding:2rem;
  font-size:2rem;
  background:#423e3f;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Just change some values in @media screen

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
.box {
  width: 50%;
  flex: auto;
}
.box:last-child {
   max-width: 50%;
}
```

}

Feel free to ask anything